# Magento CE Sample Data Installation

Tags: installation, ce-1.9.0.1, local, sample-data

I am trying to install sample data provided with Magento Community Edition ON my localhost using WAMP Server. This is the error that I get.

```
![Error](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10520842_10203085718317841_1477695816_n.jpg?oh=d593484597bfc3110935492a9f69e2e7&oe=53C3FC84&__gda__=1405350377_11c2fa90463e8445c6d7201e6b048bfe).
```

Comment: Make sure we can see the image. Follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Did you;

1. Actually create a database for your installation in PhpMyAdmin
2. Have you selected (by clicking on) the database before you went to import.

Answer (score 0):

This is more PHPMyAdmin related than Magento I think. Please use the MySQL commandline tool to import the data. If you're on Windows please use the following command

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u [username] -p [databasename] < magento_sample_data_for_1.9.0.0.sql
```